# Aero Theme - Design View

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, .net-4.0

I am currently having an issue. I have a WPF application that uses the Aero theme. In design view on a 2008 R2 server, it shows the classic theme, when I execute it, it shows the Aero theme. I have narrowed it down to this.

When I use the full path as shown below the application runs but design view does not display the theme. When I use the simple path shown below that, design view displays correctly but the application crashes saying file not found. (If I change Aero to copy local then it does run). Does anyone know how I can have my cake and eat it too?

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero,Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,processorArchitecture=MSIL;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml" />   


<ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero;component/themes/Aero.normalcolor.xaml" />
```

Comment: Seems to me that `PresentationFramework.Aero` is not included in Server 2008. You will have to include it in your application installation. And use the second line. Plus, who cares about the designer.

Comment: It the first line works then how is it not included? It's just the full GAC. And I care about the designer so I can see exactly how its going to look without having to run to test.